# Import Random dealing me the same numbers

Tags: python-3.x

I'm working on my first project, attempting to make a Black Jack game. However, the numbers that I request to generate randomly will repeat the same two number cards (ex: [4, 4] [9, 9] etc). I forgot the site that provided the tip to use random.choice, but it was very helpful to explain how to call each card.

```
import random

spades = {"Queen": 10, "Jack": 10, "King": 10, "Ace": 11}
hearts = {"Queen": 10, "Jack": 10, "King": 10, "Ace": 11}
clubs = {"Queen": 10, "Jack": 10, "King": 10, "Ace": 11}
diamonds = {"Queen": 10, "Jack": 10, "King": 10, "Ace": 11}
DECK = [random.randint(1, 10), random.choice(list(spades.keys())), 
random.choice(list(hearts.keys())), random.choice(list(clubs.keys())),random.choice(list(diamonds.keys()))]
players_hand = random.choices(DECK, weights = [36, 4, 4, 4, 4], k = 2)
dealer_hand = random.choices(DECK, weights = [36, 4, 4, 4, 4], k = 2)
print(players_hand)
```

What do I need to do to make sure the code only picks random numeric cards?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

What happens is that when random.randint generates a random value, it gets used twice but with the same value, you can fix it by adding another random.randint inside the DECK list.

Here's how to do it.

```
import random

cards = {"Queen": 10, "Jack": 10, "King": 10, "Ace": 11} 

DECK = [random.randint(1, 10) for i in range(2)] + [random.choice(list(cards.keys())) for i in range(4)]
players_hand = random.choices(DECK, weights = [36, 35, 4, 4, 4, 4], k = 2)
dealer_hand = random.choices(DECK, weights = [36, 35, 4, 4, 4, 4], k = 2)
print(players_hand)
```

I did some optimization in the code for you've been using the same value multiple times.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you, Hatem, it works well and it is much cleaner.

Please help me understand why and how did you know to input an additional 35 within the weights. If I remove it there's a value error stating the weights does not match the population.

Comment: Yup, so when you use the function choice it gives equal probability to every element in the list to appear. In our case, we don't want an equal chance. Forgive me I'm not a native English speaker. we have 9 numbers from 2 to 10. in Four types. So those are 36, and 4 images from other colors, so those are 4. Now when I draw a number out of those 36, I have 35, then the second number has 35 cards instead of 36.

Comment: You get the error, because if you add the weights parameter, you need to give a 'weight' for every element in the list, we have 5 elements in the list, hence five weights

Comment: you said "9 numbers from 2 to 10" did you mean 1 to 10?

Comment: I actually meant 2 to 10.

Comment: Yes, I now understand where I was confused. I will need to modify the .randint sequence in order to give Ace the value of 1 and 11.

Your English is just fine. Your knowledge is appreciated.
My takeaway: In this case, I needed to randomly loop through the number cards and face cards. Since you accomplished that by combining two lists, you were able to get the proper probability of each element in DECK. Good job